# Keycloak logging to logstash

Tags: logging, logstash, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

We're using [keycloak's helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/keycloak) 
I could configure internal view for logs (in webinterface). Is it possible to send these logs also to logstash?

Answer (score 8):

You can create jboss-cli scripts with logging configuration which run on Keycloak image build or container startup, see [Running custom scripts on startup](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) and [Keycloak helm chart readme](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/keycloak#wildfly-configuration). 
Below is based the Wildfly cli reference found [here](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/17.0/subsystem/logging/index.html).

### Create json formatter

`/subsystem=logging/json-formatter=json:add(key-overrides={timestamp="@timestamp"}, exception-output-type=formatted, meta-data={appname=${env.LOGSTASH_APPNAME:myApplicationName}, @version=1})`

### Create outbound socket to logstash

`/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding=log-server:add(host="${env.LOGSTASH_DESTINATION:someDefaultDestination}", port=${env.LOGSTASH_PORT:5044})`

### Create socket logging handler

`/subsystem=logging/socket-handler=log-server-handler:add(outbound-socket-binding-ref=log-server, named-formatter=json,protocol=TCP,block-on-reconnect=true)`

### Create async handler to wrap synchronous socket handler

`/subsystem=logging/async-handler=async-log-server-handler:add(level=ALL, queue-length=${env.LOGSTASH_QUEUE:1000}, overflow-action=BLOCK,subhandlers=[log-server-handler])`

### Add async handler to root logger

`/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:add-handler(name=async-log-server-handler)`

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite the Wildfly configuration file (`standalone.xml` or whatever deployment mode you use) by adding another logger, formatter and/or log handler according to the [Wildfly Logging documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/17/Admin_Guide.html#Logging)