# Keycloak 17 logging to logstash

Tags: logstash, keycloak, quarkus

Does anyone have an idea on how I can do this (what the top comments suggests): [Keycloak logging to logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62214208/18527929)
But for the newest keycloak version 17+ which uses Quarkus instead of Wildfly?

**Edit 1**:
After I have successfully added logstash feature to my keycloak+quarkus build, and `logging-gelf` shows under installed features

I can still not see logs on kibana, as if the logs are not being sent but the feature is installed.

Am I correct in thinking that this configuration is a correct "replacement" for the the Wildfly cli from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62214208/keycloak-logging-to-logstash):

```
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.enabled=true
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.json=true
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.json.key-overrides={timestamp="@timestamp"}
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.json.exception-output-type=formatted
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.json.additional-field."appname".value=${env.LOGSTASH_APPNAME:myApplicationName}
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.json.additional-field."@version".value=1

quarkus.log.handler.gelf.host=tcp:${env.LOGSTASH_DESTINATION:someDefaultDestination}
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.port=${env.LOGSTASH_PORT:5044}

#Default vale is tcp
#quarkus.log.handler.gelf.protocol=tcp
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.block-on-reconnect=true

quarkus.log.handler.gelf.async=true
#Default value is ALL
#quarkus.log.handler.gelf.level=ALL
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.async.queue-length=${env-LOGSTASH_QUEUE:1000}
#Default value is block
#quarkus.log.handler.gelf.async.overflow=block
```

Or is there some configurations that I just have "made up"?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: at the moment keycloak has no native support for gelf/logstash directly. That said, it is possible to do for sure using the quarkus logging gelf extension. In order for this to work, it is a bit complicated, but in general You have to:

1. download the jars for the quarkiverse-logging-gelf - both, the "deployment" and the runtime jar, for the quarkus version your keycloak version uses (2.7.0? Not sure, iirc I updated to 2.7.5 in 17.0.1). Also you need to download the transient dependency of this quarkus extension, namely the logstash-gelf jar in the right version. Put these jars inside the "providers" directory of your kc.
2. create a quarkus.properties file in the conf directory and add your desired configuration. There is a centralized log management guide on the quarkus homepage.
3. run a "build"
4. start Keycloak. Your log should now show

```
[io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [..., logging-gelf, ...]
```

And it should work to get your logs out the way you want it.

These steps are also described with examples e.g. [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10884#discussioncomment-2468470).

Note: I am in the Keycloak team. There is no out of the box support right now directly, bc. we are thinking about leveraging quarkus' extension approach better (so you do not have to download the jars and transient dependencies manually), but I guess for this specific case we will do something the future :)

**edit**: open pr for support using keycloak config: -> https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/12843

**edit 2**: pr merged, firstclass support should be available from the next major version (19 i guess)

Comment: Thank you for your help setting logstash up with KC, I have editted my question with configuring logstash, if you could take a look

Comment: Actually I am now looking at my kibana board, where logstash logs should be sent. And the logs are nowhere to be seen, any idea?

Comment: I found the problem. The logs were being sent, but my application sends 50k logs in the span of 20sec concluding in an overflow, and the logs not being logged in elasticsearch and Kibana. The approach that works is using syslog logging, but this won't do in my solution, as the logs are not being logged in an expected format (with a `_jsonparsefailure` tag, making it hard for searching logs. Any ideas or solutions? Is there a way to send gelf logs async, or fix syslog logs?

Comment: You could use syslog logging with quarkus.properties file created in conf directory directly as its done in the quarkus logging guide. But maybe worth to look at why 50k logs are sent and fix that instead

Comment: The problem is that I can't edit the pipeline on my ELK stack as it's on a remote server I don't have access to.
Is there a way to maybe use service such as log4j or logback to accomplish logstash logging with keycloak+quarkus?

Comment: And I have now tried with changing log level from all to info, only sending 35 logs on startup(with syslog) and none are sent with gelf